# Device ID on iOS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios, sdk

I have implemented marketingCloudSdk on Android, like this:

```
 MarketingCloudSdk.requestSdk(new MarketingCloudSdk.WhenReadyListener() {
        @Override
        public void ready(MarketingCloudSdk sdk) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("lelabs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("deviceId", sdk.getRegistrationManager().getDeviceId());
            editor.apply();
          }
      });
```

But i did not any reference to implement this listener on iOS. how should i receive Device Id using Obj-C ?

Obs: I have already implemented SDK on Android and iOS, using this steps:
https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Solved, SDK has a function called getSdkState, with this struct

```
{
    sdk_Version?: String
    dST?: Boolean
    location_Enabled?: Boolean
    etAppId?: String
    platform_Version: String
    quietPushEnabled?: Boolean
    locale?: String
    proximity_Enabled?: Boolean
    platform: String
    timeZone?: String
    hwid?: String
    push_Enabled: String
    deviceID: String
    app_Version: String
}
```

Comment: This is not a sollution.
Should should get the deviceId when you are registering for pushes on ios.
The getSDKState call just uses that but its not a trusted source.

Comment: I agree with you, I’ve registered for pushes when some user install my React Native App on App Store. Therefore, when the app start react lifecycle, I already have this deviceId registered, then I get it using native modules.